# Why is it not possible to delete files quickly (<60s) across threads in aspnet?

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, backgroundworker, delete-file

I get error

`System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file 'xxx' because it is being used by another process.'`

when I try to delete a temp file in a background worker service in aspnet core.
I am eventually allowed to delete the file after about a minute (52s, 73s).
If I change garbage collection to workstation mode, I may instead delete after ~1s (but still, a delay).

I have tried a combination of `FileOptions` to no avail, including `FileOptions.WriteThrough`.

When the controller writes the file, I use
`FlushAsync(), Close(), Dispose() and 'using'` (I know it's overkill.)
I also tried using just `File.WriteAllBytesAsync`, with same result.

In the background reader, I as well use `Close()` and `Dispose()`.
(hint: background reader will not allow me to use `DeleteOnClose`,
which would have been ideal.)

As I search stackoverflow for similar 'used by another process' issues,
all those I have found eventually resolve to
'argh it turns out I/he still had an extra open instance/reference
he forgot about',
but I have not been able to figure out that I am doing that.

Another hint:
In the writing controller, I am able to delete the file immediately
after writing it, I presume because I am still on the same thread?

Is there some secret knowledge I should read somewhere,
about being able to delete recently open files, across threads?

UPDATE: Here relevant(?) code snippets:

```
// (AspNet Controller)
        [RequestSizeLimit(9999999999)]
        [DisableFormValueModelBinding] 
        [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = MaxFileSize)]
        [HttpPost("{sessionId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UploadRevisionChunk(Guid sessionId) {
            log.LogWarning($"UploadRevisionChunk: {sessionId}");
            string uploadFolder = UploadFolder.sessionFolderPath(sessionId);
            if (!Directory.Exists(uploadFolder)) { throw new Exception($"chunk-upload failed"); }
            var cr = parseContentRange(Request);
            if (cr == null) { return this.BadRequest("no content range header specified"); }
            string chunkName = $"{cr.From}-{cr.To}";
            string saveChunkPath = Path.Combine(uploadFolder,chunkName);
            await streamToChunkFile_WAB(saveChunkPath); // write-all-bytes.
            //await streamToChunkFile_MAN(saveChunkPath); // Manual.
            long crTo   = cr.To ?? 0;
            long crFrom = cr.From ?? 0;
            long expected = (crTo - crFrom) + 1;
            var fi = new FileInfo(saveChunkPath);
            var dto = new ChunkResponse { wrote = fi.Length, expected = expected, where = "?" }; 
            string msg = $"at {crFrom}, wrote {dto.wrote} bytes (expected {dto.expected}) to {dto.where}";
            log.LogWarning(msg);
            return Ok(dto);
        }
        private async Task streamToChunkFile_WAB(string saveChunkPath) {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                Request.Body.CopyTo(ms);
                byte[] allBytes = ms.ToArray();
                await System.IO.File.WriteAllBytesAsync(saveChunkPath, allBytes);
            }
        }
```

```
// stream reader in the backgroundService:
    public class MyMultiStream : Stream {
        string[] filePaths;
        FileStream curStream = null;
        IEnumerator<string> i; 
        ILogger log;
        QueueItem qItem;

        public MyMultiStream(string[] filePaths_, Stream[] streams_, ILogger log_, QueueItem qItem_) {
            qItem = qItem_;
            log = log_;
            filePaths = filePaths_;

            log.LogWarning($"filepaths has #items: {filePaths.Length}");
            IEnumerable<string> enumerable = filePaths;
            i = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
            i.MoveNext();// necessary to prime the iterator.
        }

        public override bool CanRead { get { return true; } }
        public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }
        public override bool CanSeek { get { return false; } }
        public override long Length { get { throw new Exception("dont get length"); } }
        public override long Position {
            get { throw new Exception("dont get Position"); }
            set { throw new Exception("dont set Position"); }
        }
        public override void SetLength(long value) { throw new Exception("dont set length"); }
        public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) { throw new Exception("dont seek"); }
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) { throw new Exception("dont write"); }
        public override void Flush() { throw new Exception("dont flush"); }


        public static int openStreamCounter = 0;
        public static int closedStreamCounter = 0;
        string curFileName = "?";
        private FileStream getNextStream() {
            string nextFileName = i.Current;
            if (nextFileName == null) { throw new Exception("getNextStream should not be called past file list"); }
            //tryDelete(nextFileName,log); 
            FileStream nextStream = new FileStream(
                path:nextFileName, 
                mode: FileMode.Open, 
                access: FileAccess.Read, 
                share: FileShare.ReadWrite| FileShare.Delete,
                bufferSize:4096, // apparently default.
                options: 0
                | FileOptions.Asynchronous 
                | FileOptions.SequentialScan
                // | FileOptions.DeleteOnClose // (1) this ought to be possible, (2) we should fix this approach (3) if we can fix this, our issue is solved, and our code much simpler.
            ); // None); // ReadWrite); // None); // ReadWrite); //| FileShare.Read);
            log.LogWarning($"TELLUS making new stream [{nextFileName}] opened:[{++openStreamCounter}] closed:[{closedStreamCounter}]");

            curFileName = nextFileName;
            ++qItem.chunkCount;
            return nextStream;
        }

        public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count) {
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while (true) {
                bytesRead = 0;
                if (curStream == null) { curStream = getNextStream(); }
                try {
                    bytesRead = curStream.Read(buffer, offset, count);
                    log.LogWarning($"..bytesRead:{bytesRead} [{Path.GetFileName(curFileName)}]"); // (only show a short name.)
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.LogError($"failed reading [{curFileName}] [{e.Message}]",e);
                }
                if (bytesRead > 0) { break; }

                curStream.Close();
                curStream.Dispose();
                curStream = null;
                log.LogWarning($"TELLUS closing stream [{curFileName}] opened:[{openStreamCounter}] closed:[{++closedStreamCounter}]");
                //tryDelete(curFileName); Presumably we can't delete so soon.
                bool moreFileNames = i.MoveNext();
                log.LogWarning($"moreFileNames?{moreFileNames}");
                if (!moreFileNames) {
                    break; 
                }
            }
            return bytesRead; 
        }

..
// Background worker operating multistream:
    public class BackgroundChunkWorker: BackgroundService { 
        ILogger L;
        ChunkUploadQueue q; 

        public readonly IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory;

        public BackgroundChunkWorker(ILogger<int> log_, ChunkUploadQueue q_, IServiceScopeFactory scopeFactory_) {
            q = q_; L = log_;
            scopeFactory = scopeFactory_;
        }

        override protected async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancel) { await BackgroundProcessing(cancel); }

        private async Task BackgroundProcessing(CancellationToken cancel) {
            while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested) {
                try {
                    await Task.Delay(1000,cancel);
                    bool ok = q.q.TryDequeue(out var item);
                    if (!ok) { continue; }
                    L.LogInformation($"item found! {item}");
                    await treatItemScope(item);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    L.LogCritical("An error occurred when processing. Exception: {@Exception}", ex);
                }
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> treatItemScope(QueueItem Qitem) {
            using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope()) {
                var ris = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IRevisionIntegrationService>();
                return await treatItem(Qitem, ris);
            }
        }

        private async Task<bool> treatItem(QueueItem Qitem, IRevisionIntegrationService ris) {
            await Task.Delay(0);
            L.LogWarning($"TryAddValue from P {Qitem.sessionId}");
            bool addOK = q.p.TryAdd(Qitem.sessionId, Qitem);
            if (!addOK) {
                L.LogError($"why couldnt we add session {Qitem.sessionId} to processing-queue?");
                return false; 
            }

            var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            Guid revisionId = Qitem.revisionId; 

            string[] filePaths = getFilePaths(Qitem.sessionId);

            Stream[] streams = filePaths.Select(fileName => new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open)).ToArray();
            MyMultiStream multiStream = new MyMultiStream(filePaths, streams, this.L, Qitem);
            BimRevisionStatus brs = await ris.UploadRevision(revisionId, multiStream, startTime);
            // (launchDeletes is my current hack/workaround,
            // it is not part of the problem)
            // await multiStream.launchDeletes();
            Qitem.status = brs;
            return true;
        }
..
```

Comment: Without seeing your code we can just say that typically those behavior occur when you still have a handle on the file open like you said yourself. Try to show the relevant involved code.

Comment: Have you tried to observe the file with the tool 'SysInternals Process Explorer'? Just to see which process is responsible and still using this file.

Comment: The File System itself also plays into this. It _may_ hold locks longer than actually needed (or expected).

Comment: Could you please share your relevant code snippet where you are getting the above specified error.

Comment: sysinternals/ @rubgra: Yes, it reports iisexpress, that is, my own aspnet code.

Comment: I have updated the body with the failing code parts.
Know that the code _seems_ to work - the background queue can read,
and eventually I can also delete the files.
But I don't understand why I can't delete immediately on close.
   Note that ```launchDeletes``` is not part of the problem,
it is just my current workaround.